# How do I select the comment block under the cursor in vim?

Tags: vim, selection

I’d like to select (or delete, or change, or …) the whole block of commentary under my cursor.

If my cursor is at the *beginning* of the commentary block (i.e. over the opening comment character), and it’s a type of comment block with discrete start/end markers, then I can select the entire comment block with <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>, but I don’t know of a movement to move to the first character of the block currently under the cursor.

Better yet would be an inner-text object for comments.

Does anybody know of any of the above, or how I could easily create the latter? (I’m new to vim as a whole.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're working with C++ block comments, these commands should do what you want:

1. `[/`
2. `v`
3. `]/`

These will:

1. The first will jump to the start of a block comment (the slash in /*)
2. The second will turn on select mode
3. The third will jump to the end of a block comment (the slash in */), which selects the entire comment block.

I hope that helps!

EDIT: One note about using the lower case v instead of the upper case V. The upper case V will select entire lines while the lower case v will only select the text from the cursor's start position to the end position. Using the lower case v also means not having to hit the shift key. :)

Comment: `[` and `]`.  Two more incredibly useful nav commands for my vim vocabulary, to go alongside `f` and `t` :) Thanks

Comment: You can also use % for the 3. step, which is easier to type in many keyboards.

Comment: I am trying to use this in my `.vimrc` (`["v]"`) but it does not work. Do I miss something?